# Print the largest and smallest number without list

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program find smallest and biggest I made a code like that I can read the inputs, program can do the thing but I can not construct the inside of the loop. I believe it can be like that.

```
count = 1
number = 0

while number != -1:
    number = int(input(str(count)+'. number'))
    '''
    ######################
    '''
    count += 1
print(''+str(###))
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use a `set`?

Comment: This is a fairly simple exercise, you should think it by yourself imo. It's the only way to learn.

Comment: Yes, there is no restriction about set. @Czaporka

Comment: I am new at python so I can not find a way maybe you can teach me @Gamopo

Comment: Actually nevermind `set`, Gamopo's comment made me realize that in this sort of exercise you don't really need to store all the numbers - you just need to keep 2 integers "current min" and "current max", and update them accordingly from within the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import  math
count = 1
largest = -math.inf
smallest = math.inf

while True:
    n = int(input(str(count)+'. number'))
    if n == -1:
        break
    if largest < n:
        largest = n
    if smallest > n:
        smallest = n
    count += 1
print(largest," ", smallest)
```

Comment: You could use `float('inf')` and  `float('-inf')` and avoid importing `math`.

Answer (score 3):

At each iteration store the min and max values you saw so far and if the current number s bigger\ smaller update them.

```
maxNum = -1
minNum = sys.maxsize -1

while number != -1:
    number = int(input(str(count)+'. number'))
    if number == -1:
        break
    minNum = min(minNum, number)
    maxNum = max(maxNum, number)
    count += 1

print(''+str(...))
print(f'min: {minNum}')
print(f'max: {maxNum}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of 3 numbers at all time : the lowest input, the highest input and the number that is input. So you just have to store the 3 variables and check at each input if the user inputs a number higher than the present highest or lower than the present lowest

```
largest = -1
lowest = -1
number = 0
while number != -1:
    number = int(input("enter your number :"))
    if (number > largest):
        largest = number
    if (number < lowest):
        lowest = number
print(lowest, largest)
```